# Interactive transition: navigation bar appearance issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Lets's say, I have 3 view controllers: `A`, `B`, `C`, all embedded into a navigation controller. `A` and `B` have a navigation bar, `C` doesn't.

I have a custom interactive transition between `B` and `C`. Since I need my navigation bar to disappear on `C`, I implemented this function of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewController is C {
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }
    else {
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly in an common scenario, when I only make push-pop transitions.

But when I **cancel** transition `B`->`C` by calling `cancel()` on my `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, the navigation bar doesn't show up on `B`. Here I have to call `setNavigationBarHidden(false, ...)`, but I haven't managed to find the correct place to do it.

If I call it in `B`'s `viewWillAppear`, navigation bar appears, but looks really strange - it contains elements which the `C` would have if it had navigation bar. If I pop back to the `A`, it will blink for a moment with expected contents, but immediately after transition the `A` navigation bar gets replaced by the `B` navigation bar!

So, it seems like the navigation bars stack is somehow broken after `B`->`C` transition cancellation, it appears to be shifted relatively to viewcontrollers like that:

```
                      has
-----------------------------------------------
|    ViewController    |   Navigation bar of  |
-----------------------------------------------
|           A          |           B          |
-----------------------------------------------
|           B          |           C          |
-----------------------------------------------
```

So, my question is what's the correct place to call `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've managed to find an ugly hack to fix it by myself. Maybe someone in this world would find it helpful.

- In my custom `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` I override `cancel` function like that:

  ```
  class CustomTransitionManager: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {

      /// Indicates transition direction. Must be set before each transition.
      var forward: Bool = true

      /// Current navigation controller used for transition. Must be set before transition starts
      var nc: UINavigationController?

      /**
       * Hack #1 with UINavigationController here
       */
      override func cancel() {
          super.cancel()

          if forward {
              self.nc?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
          }
          self.nc?.setNavigationBarHidden(forward, animated: false)
      }
  }
  ```
- In each of the view controllers (A, B, C) I make the following hack:

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      // Hide and immediately show navigation bar: this will restore it's correct state
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
  }
  ```

The best solution probably would be a modal fullscreen presentation of `C`, but in my case I am working with a project already having corrupted navigation hierarchy and I had no time to fix it properly. Basically, that's the reason why I faced this issue.